# np.where not working as expected on new Image

Tags: python, image, np

I am working on a morphing project that requires delauney and creating polygons. I have to find where the image is white or black. I know I need to use np.where, however, when I do, it returns an empty array. This is even true when I try to search for the black pixels on a black image. I believe it may be because I am passing the np.where function a PIL image, but when I try to convert it to an np.array, I get an error message.

```
    black = Image.new('1', (1440, 1080), color = "black")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(black)

    draw.polygon([point1, point2, point3], fill = "white")

    vals = np.where(np.all(black == [0, 0, 0]))
    print(vals)
```

I expect to get all the locations of black pixels.